# Issue With Custom Collection Model Binder in MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, model-binding, modelbinders

I'm having an issue creating a model binder in MVC.

The action that I'm targeting looks like:

```
public ActionResult GetAccounts (ICollection<Account> accounts ){}
```

I created a custom model binder and registered it with the following code:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(ICollection<Account>),new CollectionModelBinder());
```

With a debugger attached, I can see that the `CollectionModelBinder's CreateModel` method is being called.  However, when execution reaches the action method of the controller, the accounts parameter is null.

What's the issue?

My model binder looks like:

```
public class CollectionModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    protected override object CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType)
    {
        return new List<Account> {
            new Account {Id = 1}, 
            new Account {Id = 2}, 
            new Account {Id = 3}};
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

This was a problem with `DefaultModelBinder.`  After `CreateModel` was called, another internal method, `UpdateCollection` was called, which effectively nulled out the collection that was created by `CreateModel.` The solution was to roll my own implementation of `IModelBinder.`  The only argument that's missing on `IModelBinder.BindModel` is the `modelType,` which is easy to get:

```
public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
{
    var type = bindingContext.ModelType;
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a problem with `DefaultModelBinder.`  After `CreateModel` was called, another internal method, `UpdateCollection` was called, which effectively nulled out the collection that was created by `CreateModel.` The solution was to roll my own implementation of `IModelBinder.`  The only argument that's missing on `IModelBinder.BindModel` is the `modelType,` which is easy to get:

```
public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
{
    var type = bindingContext.ModelType;
    //...
}
```